# Concatenate and Display results in CEWP

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, content-editor-web-part

I have two **Content Editor Webparts** in a page(CEWP) in a SharePoint page. In the first CEWP I have two html text boxes and one button. If i click on the
button in first CEWP the second CEWP will display the result in page.
How to concatenate and display the result.

Answer (score 0):

Its not needed to use two CEWP, you can achieve it in a single CEWP itself. After your html textbox and buttons add a 'div' tag as below.

```
<div id="displayresults" />
```

On click event of your button, call a JavaScript function that will your results to the div like below,

```
var resultdiv = $("#displayresults");
var resultTable="<Your results in html format>";
$(resultTable).appendTo(resultdiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ID in the HTML elements.

Example

**first content editor**

```
<input type="button" onclick="SetSecondC();" values="Click" />

function SetSecondC() {
    document.getElementById('txtSecond').value = "Message";
}
```

**second content editor**

```
<input type="text" id="txtSecond" />
```